# How to use builde customize view in a storyboard-ed project?

Tags: ios, uiview, uitableview, storyboard

I have a project with storyboard. I want to make a customized view for a tableview section header. I created a xib in the interface builder. But how do I load it and return for the header view?

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    VAHeaderView *headerView = [[VAHeaderView alloc] initWithItem:item];
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"VAItemDetailHeaderView" owner:self options:nil];

    return headerView;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Leo

Answer (score 0):

The definition of the viewForHeaderInSection method is this:
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section

To achieve what you're trying to do you will need to do some programming work. But you'll notice that the method simply returns a "UIView*". You can do a new viewcontroller in interfacebuilder and simply use the view from that one in your headers.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    HeaderViewController * headerViewController = [[HeaderViewController alloc] initWithTitle:@"Header title"];
    return headerViewController.view;  
}
```

Comment: I guess you mean I can create a xib file and its associated view controller but just use the view generated by `[HeaderViewController alloc] initWithNibNamed:@"header"]`?